What about Quant Events ?
Hi,
I think that hte Meta is the right place to ask if announcements of Quant Events such as Seminars, Conferences,etc.. are welcome in the forum (or under what conditions they should be) ? 
Best Regards

Yes, chat is the only forum that permits this kind of thing within the StackExchange system.
I should add: chat is a really great tool.  Some of us spend a lot of time in there.  It would be great to see more people joining in.

This is certainly the right place to ask your question.  I would say announcements are not welcome, ever.  That would open the door for tons of "questions" that will destroy the signal-noise ratio.  Announcing them on chat would be fine though.

I assume you're referring to the recent blog post. There's this announcement from Jeff, which was a who-would-like-to-attend. I think that's a possible way to post it, since discussions are more permissible in Meta.
